# Linking through nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models: posts, comments and questions and am trying to link from posts to questions.

My routes.rb file looks like this:

```
resources :posts do
 resources :comments do
end
end

resources :comments do
 resources :questions do
 end
end
```

Here is the posts view file:

```
<% post.comments.select(:body).order('created_at desc').limit(2).each do |comment| %>
<%= link_to (comment.body), comment_questions_path(#what to pass in here?) %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried:

```
<%= link_to (comment.body), comment_questions_path(comment, @question) %>
```

error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"questions", :action=>"index", :comment_id=>#<Comment id: nil, body: "Describe what it was like to witness the explosion?...">, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:comment_id]    <%= link_to (comment.body), comment_questions_path(#what to pass in here?) %>
```

and:

```
 <%= link_to (comment.body), comment_questions_path(:comment_id, question) %>
```

error:

```
 Couldn't find Comment with id=comment_id
```

and:

```
<%= link_to (comment.body), comment_questions_path(:comment_id, :id) >
```

error:

```
 Couldn't find Comment with id=comment_id
```

Here is the route:

```
comment_questions GET    /comments/:comment_id/questions(.:format)            questions#index
```

Thanks for the help!
and the index function in questions controller:

```
def index
@comment = Comment.find params[:comment_id]
@questions = @comment.questions
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drop the `.select(:body)`. This makes it give the body attribute back but doesn't enable you to properly work with the object.

Then try:

```
link_to comment.body, comment_questions_path( comment )
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your terminal:

```
$ rake routes
```